# Restore Site Collection From Farm Backup

Tags: powershell, backup, restore

We are planning to implement a backup-restore process for our SharePoint farm and i have couple of questions and i would greatly appreciate if someone helps me with that

Our Environment : I am planning to perform a full backup of entire SharePoint farm and from then i want to do differential backup everyday.We have about 1500 site collections spread across different web applications

Question 1 
When i did a full farm backup it produced weird names such as 00001A.bak and so on .So if i want to restore a single site collection from the farm backup ,How can i achieve that

Question 2
As i am planning to do differential backup .How can i restore a single site collection from the farm differential backup .

If this is not possible can you guys please suggest me any advice regarding the scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to try and address both your questions with a single answer.

Unfortunately, you are not going to be able to restore a particular site collection with the route your headed in.

What you'll have to do is back up the content database by using SharePoint Farm Backup or SQL Server Backup and then use the unattached content database restore option.

Here is an official link to help you through that:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh269601(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks you very much .This link really helped me a lot .I have one more question .If we are restoring all the site collections in the farm using power shell .Do we need to have the Farm Backup everyday

Comment: If you are looking to restore all site collections only (not the entire farm) then you are going to have to right a shell script (as opposed to manually having to backup each site collection from CA) to run through each and back it up - http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Backup-all-collections-in-726514cb.
If you only need to backup your site collections (a few or all) then just use a script to back all of them up as opposed to wating time/space on a spfarm backup.

Comment: Here are a few more reference links:
1. http://pathikhrawal.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/sharepoint-2010-backup-and-recovery-guidelines/

2. http://www.fewlines4biju.com/2012/02/difference-between-granular-and-farm.html